# android studio log erorr Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. it open and closes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

i know this may not be new i just need to get it working.

I have created api key and puted it on manifest file still it not working.in my logcat it gives me error
i have enable place api for my api
my error log 
2020-04-11 22:57:13.514 7579-7579/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2020-04-11 22:57:14.331 1300-2669/? E/Volley: [144] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/autocompleteWidget?key=AIzaSyDYu4t
2020-04-11 22:57:14.543 1300-5696/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
2020-04-11 22:57:14.583 1300-5696/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=AutocompleteWidgetQuota
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}]
        at bicw.a(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):1)
        at bici.a(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):4)
        at aakp.run(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):8)
        at blfm.run(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):2)
        at tad.b(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):12)
        at tad.run(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at tgd.run(:com.google.android.gms@200914016@20.09.14 (040304-300565878):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2020-04-11 22:57:14.588 7553-7553/? E/Places: Autocomplete widget closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED

here is my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.general.files.GeneralFunctions;
import com.general.files.GetAddressFromLocation;
import com.general.files.GetLocationUpdates;
import com.general.files.StartActProcess;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.utils.Utils;
import com.view.MButton;
import com.view.MTextView;
import com.view.MaterialRippleLayout;

public class SearchPickupLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GetAddressFromLocation.AddressFound,GetLocationUpdates.LocationUpdates {

    private String TAG = SearchPickupLocationActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    MTextView titleTxt;
    ImageView backImgView;

    GeneralFunctions generalFunc;
    MButton btn_type2;
    int btnId;

    MTextView placeTxtView;

    boolean isPlaceSelected = false;
    LatLng placeLocation;
    Marker placeMarker;

    SupportMapFragment map;
    GoogleMap gMap;

    GetAddressFromLocation getAddressFromLocation;
    LinearLayout placeArea;
    MTextView homePlaceTxt;
    MTextView workPlaceTxt;

    String userHomeLocationLatitude_str;
    String userHomeLocationLongitude_str;
    String userWorkLocationLatitude_str;
    String userWorkLocationLongitude_str;
    String home_address_str;
    String work_address_str;
    SharedPreferences mpref_place;
    GetLocationUpdates getLastLocation;
    private Location userLocation;
    private Marker locMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_pickup_location);

        generalFunc = new GeneralFunctions(getActContext());


        titleTxt = (MTextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
        backImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backImgView);
        btn_type2 = ((MaterialRippleLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_type2)).getChildView();
        placeTxtView = (MTextView) findViewById(R.id.placeTxtView);

        homePlaceTxt = (MTextView) findViewById(R.id.homePlaceTxt);
        workPlaceTxt = (MTextView) findViewById(R.id.workPlaceTxt);
        placeArea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.placeArea);

        map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapV2);

        getAddressFromLocation = new GetAddressFromLocation(getActContext(), generalFunc);
        getAddressFromLocation.setAddressList(this);

        getLastLocation = new GetLocationUpdates(getActContext(), 8);
        getLastLocation.setLocationUpdatesListener(this);

        setLabels();

        map.getMapAsync(SearchPickupLocationActivity.this);

        backImgView.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        btnId = Utils.generateViewId();
        btn_type2.setId(btnId);

        btn_type2.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        (findViewById(R.id.pickUpLocSearchArea)).setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        homePlaceTxt.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());
        workPlaceTxt.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickAct());

        generalFunc.showMessage(generalFunc.getCurrentView(SearchPickupLocationActivity.this), generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_LONG_TOUCH_CHANGE_LOC_TXT"));


        checkLocations();
    }

    public void setLabels() {
        placeTxtView.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_SEARCH_PLACE_HINT_TXT"));
        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isPickUpLoc") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isPickUpLoc").equals("true")) {
            titleTxt.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_SET_PICK_UP_LOCATION_TXT"));


        } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isHome") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isHome").equals("true")) {
            titleTxt.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_ADD_HOME_BIG_TXT"));
            homePlaceTxt.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("Home Place", "LBL_HOME_PLACE"));
        } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isWork") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isWork").equals("true")) {
            titleTxt.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_ADD_WORK_HEADER_TXT"));
            workPlaceTxt.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("Work Place", "LBL_WORK_PLACE"));
        } else {
            titleTxt.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_SELECT_DESTINATION_HEADER_TXT"));
        }

        btn_type2.setText(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_ADD_LOC"));




    }


    public void checkLocations() {
        mpref_place = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActContext());
        home_address_str = mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationAddress", null);

        userHomeLocationLatitude_str = mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationLatitude", null);
        userHomeLocationLongitude_str = mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationLongitude", null);

        work_address_str = mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationAddress", null);
        userWorkLocationLatitude_str = mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationLatitude", null);
        userWorkLocationLongitude_str = mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationLongitude", null);

        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isHome") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isHome").equals("true")) {

            if (home_address_str != null && !home_address_str.equals("")) {
                homePlaceTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                placeArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                (findViewById(R.id.seperationLine)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isWork") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isWork").equals("true")) {

            if (work_address_str != null && !work_address_str.equals("")) {
                workPlaceTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                placeArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                (findViewById(R.id.seperationLine)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        this.gMap = googleMap;

        mpref_place = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActContext());

        if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isPickUpLoc") != null && getIntent().hasExtra("PickUpLatitude") && getIntent().hasExtra("PickUpLongitude")) {

            LatLng placeLocation = new LatLng(generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, getIntent().getStringExtra("PickUpLatitude")),
                    generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, getIntent().getStringExtra("PickUpLongitude")));

            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(placeLocation, 14.0f);
            gMap.moveCamera(cu);

        } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isHome") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isHome").equals("true") && home_address_str != null && !home_address_str.equals("")) {
            if (mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationLatitude", null) != null && mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationLongitude", null) != null) {
                LatLng HomeLocation = new LatLng(generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationLatitude", "0.0")),
                        generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationLongitude", "0.0")));
                if (HomeLocation.latitude != 0.0 && HomeLocation.longitude != 0.0) {
                    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HomeLocation, 14.0f);
//                    addMarker(HomeLocation);
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HomeLocation).title(mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationAddress", "")));

                    gMap.moveCamera(cu);
                }
            }
            placeTxtView.setText("" + mpref_place.getString("userHomeLocationAddress", ""));

        } else if (getIntent().getStringExtra("isWork") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("isWork").equals("true") && work_address_str != null && !work_address_str.equals("")) {
            if (mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationLatitude", null) != null && mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationLongitude", null) != null) {
                LatLng WorkLocation = new LatLng(generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationLatitude", "0.0")),
                        generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationLongitude", "0.0")));
                if (WorkLocation.latitude != 0.0 && WorkLocation.longitude != 0.0) {
                    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(WorkLocation, 14.0f);
//                    addMarker(WorkLocation);
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(WorkLocation).title(mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationAddress", "")));
                    gMap.moveCamera(cu);
                }
            }
            placeTxtView.setText("" + mpref_place.getString("userWorkLocationAddress", ""));

        } else {
            Utils.printLog("Api", "in loc upadate" + userLocation);

            if (userLocation != null) {
                LatLng UserLocation = new LatLng(generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, "" + userLocation.getLatitude()),
                        generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, "" + userLocation.getLongitude()));
                Utils.printLog("Api", "in loc upadate" + UserLocation);
                if (UserLocation != null) {
//                    addMarker(UserLocation);
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(UserLocation));
                    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(UserLocation, 14.0f);
                    gMap.moveCamera(cu);
                }
            } else {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService
                        (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                Location getLastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation
                        (LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
                if (getLastLocation != null) {
                    LatLng UserLocation = new LatLng(generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, "" + getLastLocation.getLatitude()),
                            generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, "" + getLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                    Utils.printLog("Api", "in loc upadate" + UserLocation);
                    if (UserLocation != null) {
//                        addMarker(UserLocation);
//                        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(UserLocation));
//                        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(UserLocation, 14.0f);
//                        gMap.moveCamera(cu);

                        getAddressFromLocation.setLocation(UserLocation.latitude, UserLocation.longitude);
                        getAddressFromLocation.setLoaderEnable(true);
                        getAddressFromLocation.execute();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        this.gMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                getAddressFromLocation.setLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
                getAddressFromLocation.setLoaderEnable(true);
                getAddressFromLocation.execute();
            }
        });

    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng location) {
        MarkerOptions marker_opt = new MarkerOptions().position(location);
        marker_opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_dest_marker)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        locMarker = this.gMap.addMarker(marker_opt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdate(Location location) {
        userLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddressFound(String address, double latitude, double longitude, String geocodeobject) {
        Utils.printLog("address", ":" + address);
        placeTxtView.setText(address);
        isPlaceSelected = true;
        this.placeLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(this.placeLocation, 14.0f);

        if (gMap != null) {
            gMap.clear();
            placeMarker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(this.placeLocation).title(address));
            gMap.moveCamera(cu);
        }
    }

    public class setOnClickAct implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int i = view.getId();
            if (i == R.id.backImgView) {
                SearchPickupLocationActivity.super.onBackPressed();

            } else if (i == R.id.pickUpLocSearchArea) {
                try {

                    LatLngBounds bounds = null;

                    if (getIntent().hasExtra("PickUpLatitude") && getIntent().hasExtra("PickUpLongitude")) {

                        LatLng pickupPlaceLocation = new LatLng(generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, getIntent().getStringExtra("PickUpLatitude")),
                                generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, getIntent().getStringExtra("PickUpLongitude")));
                        bounds = new LatLngBounds(pickupPlaceLocation, pickupPlaceLocation);
                    }

                    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                            .setBoundsBias(bounds)
                            .build(SearchPickupLocationActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Utils.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);


                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    generalFunc.showMessage(generalFunc.getCurrentView(SearchPickupLocationActivity.this),
                            generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("", "LBL_SERVICE_NOT_AVAIL_TXT"));
                }
            } else if (i == btnId) {

                if (isPlaceSelected == false) {
                    generalFunc.showMessage(generalFunc.getCurrentView(SearchPickupLocationActivity.this),
                            generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("Please set location.", "LBL_SET_LOCATION"));
                    return;
                }

                Bundle bn = new Bundle();
                bn.putString("Address", placeTxtView.getText().toString());
                bn.putString("Latitude", "" + placeLocation.latitude);
                bn.putString("Longitude", "" + placeLocation.longitude);

                new StartActProcess(getActContext()).setOkResult(bn);
                backImgView.performClick();
            } else if (i == homePlaceTxt.getId()) {
                onAddressFound(home_address_str, generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, userHomeLocationLatitude_str),
                        generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, userHomeLocationLongitude_str),"");
            } else if (i == workPlaceTxt.getId()) {
                onAddressFound(work_address_str, generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, userWorkLocationLatitude_str),
                        generalFunc.parseDoubleValue(0.0, userWorkLocationLongitude_str),"");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Utils.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                Utils.printLog(TAG, "Place:" + place.toString());

                placeTxtView.setText(place.getAddress());
                isPlaceSelected = true;
                LatLng placeLocation = place.getLatLng();

                this.placeLocation = placeLocation;

                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(placeLocation, 14.0f);

                if (gMap != null) {
                    gMap.clear();
                    placeMarker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(placeLocation).title("" + place.getAddress()));
                    gMap.moveCamera(cu);
                }

            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                Utils.printLog(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

                generalFunc.showMessage(generalFunc.getCurrentView(SearchPickupLocationActivity.this),
                        status.getStatusMessage());
            } else if (requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }
        }
    }

    public Context getActContext() {
        return SearchPickupLocationActivity.this;
    }

}
```

my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    //    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    Implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    Implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1+'
    Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    Implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
    Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.app85taxi.passenger.SearchPickupLocationActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_include"
        layout="@layout/design_toolbar_general" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapV2"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/pickUpLocSearchArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_search" />

                <com.view.MTextView
                    android:id="@+id/placeTxtView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/seperationLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="#cecece"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/placeArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <com.view.MTextView
                    android:id="@+id/homePlaceTxt"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Home Place"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="#cecece" />

                <com.view.MTextView
                    android:id="@+id/workPlaceTxt"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Work Place"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <include
            android:id="@+id/btn_type2"
            layout="@layout/btn_type_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/all_btn_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-8dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you haven't enabled places API and Maps API in your google cloud console for this project or you haven't set you Application's SHA1 to your project.
Verify first that you have selected the right project and enabled Places API for android or not.
Also, you need to enable billing for your account which I think you have already enabled.
You can check that you have enabled places API or not over this link.

Make sure to select your project from the top of the window first.

[Places API](https://cloud.google.com/console/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com)

Comment: i have done the enabling of google cloud console for the api also the billing only the sha1 would try that now

Comment: any other idea i can use or do    @Baljeet

Comment: oh, now I saw what's wrong. You are using old places API SDK which is now officially turned off. You can check this page for more info. You have to migrate your project to the latest Places SDK. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: can u help me out with that am finding it difficult to understand @Baljeet

Comment: As i can see you are using a very old version of both firebase, play service, places API etc so you have to do a number of changes as latest firebase plugin versions are >17.0 and places SDK v2 is totally new standalone SDK so first upgrade all version of libraries in your project only after that you can see what error comes to your way.. first upgrade all libraries then follow this guide https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration